# Uniquely Identy Wordpress Installation

Tags: wordpress, api

I am working on an API for wordpress and I am looking for a way to uniquely identify a wordpress installation that is requesting the API. Does anyone know of a install id or unique wordpress blog id? Is that even a thing?

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/q/28916851/139010

Answer (score 1):

I have written 2 APIs and have worked with several, I stumbled upon this question long time back...

I like to keep the stuff simple... so I use `site_url()` as identity of the blog, since I'm sure no other installation would run on the same site url so whenever there is an issue to debug, I know site ID is the url.
Saved one extra field in my DB ( If I had ID different, I'd need another field for site url ).

You can also go for complex solutions like using md5 of site_url along with some random generated strings to name a few.

---

### Update

This will generate an ID on activation and save it in the database.

```
function generate_password($length = 12) {
  $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';

  $password = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $password. = substr($chars, rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1), 1);
  }

  return $password;
}

function my_plugin_activated() {
  $id = generate_password();
  add_option('my_plugin_installation_id', $id);
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_activated' );
```

Code in `my_plugin_activated()` is executed only once on activation of plugin ( you can do the same for theme  ), you can, in activation hook itself, make a call to your api and get the site registered in your db.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The issue I would worry about with this is that site URL is very easy to spoof and if the request comes from a Wordpress install behind a cdn I have no way to validate that it coming from the same place.

Comment: Hmm... in that case... you can randomly generate an ID for the installation... Adding code to the answer ;)

Comment: That makes sense I just worry that someone could take the api key the unique key and make calls from other installation.

Comment: Hi, I recently wrote an api for updating WordPress plugins and used the similar code... In my code... `my_plugin_installation_id` is a value in an array which is looped through... This makes it difficult to discover the option name... it was sufficient for me but if you like you can try stuff like first 7 characters from md5 of site url to make it extremely difficult to find...

Comment: For example md5 of `http://example.com/` `a6bf1757fff057f266b697df9cf176fd` you can use `a6bf175_site_id` as option name, you can get creative and use any prefix and/or suffix to make it even harder to find out ;)

Comment: How does it sound? Is the solution overkill for you?